# how to findout whether my database has been hacked or not

Tags: database

How to find out whether a my website database has been hacked or not by any one?

Comment: Ummm, look inside and see if anything doesn't look right, e.g. you lost any data, some strange data was inserted, or *gasp* your tables are gone?

Comment: Logs (and the odor of mischief). The details would be DB specific.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which database server your using(Oracle, MySql, etc) and your hosting server, you should have log files which would monitor change or login activities. However someone who is careful would clean out log entries has well.

Database entries can changed by a number of factor. Not necessary meaning someone hacked it.

Basically its all about prevention. Set edit Log permissions only to Superuser/Admin. Don't log in as superuser unless you really have too. Have permission based user accounts for yourself and/or for anyone/anything else that requires access to the database.